# Updating Sum Case Statement Grouped By Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create update statement that will enable to sum converted values and write appropriate result based on case statement into database. This also must be grouped by id as we store answers that are then calculated and appropriate result must be saved to easy with analysing data. 
I finally gave up after trying too many things and for today have enough. Could anyone with good heart and knowledge help please?

Below is the script I end up at the moment.

```
Update DB.sf_snew
Set answer = 
    (Case When
            sum(cast(question1 as Int)) +  sum(cast(question2 Int)) 
            + sum(cast(question3 as Int)) 
            <= 20 Then 'reject' Else 'accept' 
    End
    )
Group By Id
```

**I cannot believe something that simple made my day really bad.**
**I appreciate any help from you.**

Below is the example of data stored in a snwew table
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your question has numerous syntax errors and it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is ID a unique key? what is they structure of the table you are trying to update?

Comment: If `Id` is unique, then the query should work fine if the `group by...` line is removed.

Comment: Hi GolfWolf, Yes tried group by but it does not like it otherwise it count all data in every row and sum up into one row. In my example I need to count all recirds grouping them by id.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the sums and the group by:

```
Update DB.sf_snew
Set answer = 
Case When
        cast(question1 as Int) +  cast(question2 Int)
        + cast(question3 as Int)
        <= 20 Then 'reject' Else 'accept' 
End
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go and let you later this week.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an aggregate, just do the following:

```
UPDATE DB.sf_snew
SET Answer = CASE WHEN CAST(Question1 AS INT) + CAST(Question2 AS INT) + CAST(Question3 AS INT) <= 20 THEN 'Reject' ELSE 'Accept' END
```

The UPDATE will automatically work row-by-row

Comment: Thanks, same solution to Obie ..,this make me think optimistic ;)